# Latex newcommand with key-values uses value of last call for each call

Tags: macros, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I'm currently trying to build a wrapper command for \glsxtrnewsymbol for my glossary, that uses keyvalues to keep it more organised(example how a call of the function should look like see attached).

```
\addysmbol{
    ref = input-voltage,
    description = Input Voltage,
    name = \ensuremath{U_{out}},
    unit = \si{\volt},
}
```

So far I've tried to do it with pgfkeys and keyval, but with both encountered the error that it uses the passed arguments of the last call of the function for all functions.

```
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{keyval}

\define@key{test}{unit}{%
    \def\thisunit{#1}}
\define@key{test}{ref}{%
    \edef\thisref{#1}}
\define@key{test}{description}{%
    \edef\thisdescription{#1}}
\define@key{test}{name}{%
    \edef\thisname{#1}}



\newcommand*{\addsymbol}[1]{%%
    \setkeys{test}{#1}%
    \glsxtrnewsymbol[description={\thisdescription},unit=\thisunit]{\thisref}{\thisname}%%  
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: your example can not be tested as it is incomplete. But apart from this: do not use \edef with arbitrary text. Depending on the content of the text it can break your code.

Comment: you presumably want to add a group to `\newcommand*{\addsymbol}` to limit the scope of `\setkeys`

Comment: But adding a group also limits the scope of \glsxtrnewsymbol

Comment: tex is a macro expansion language using `\addsymbol{a=b}` is just the same  as using `\setkeys{test}{a=b}\glsxtrnewsymbol...`  they have the same scope, unlike a functional language a macro never implies any local scope for names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably nesting `\PassFirstToSecond`/`\Exchange` does the trick:

```latex
\makeatletter

\RequirePackage{keyval}

\define@key{test}{unit}{\def\thisunit{#1}}%
\define@key{test}{ref}{\protected@edef\thisref{#1}}%
\define@key{test}{description}{\protected@edef\thisdescription{#1}}%
\define@key{test}{name}{\protected@edef\thisname{#1}}%

\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%

\newcommand*{\addsymbol}[1]{%%
    \begingrpup
    \setkeys{test}{#1}%
    \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\thisname}{%
      \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\thisref}{%
        \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\thisunit}{%
          \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\thidescription}{%
            \endgroup\glsxtrnewsymbol[description=%
          },unit=%
        }]%
      }%
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

If you work with a TeX-engine where the primitives `\expanded` and `\unnexpanded` are available, the following might do the trick:

```latex
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{keyval}

\define@key{test}{unit}{\def\thisunit{#1}}%
\define@key{test}{ref}{\def\thisref{#1}}%
\define@key{test}{description}{\def\thisdescription{#1}}%
\define@key{test}{name}{\def\thisname{#1}}%


\newcommand*{\addsymbol}[1]{%%
    \begingroup
    \setkeys{test}{#1}%
    \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
    \expanded{%
      \endgroup
      \noexpand\glsxtrnewsymbol
      [description={\thisdescription},%
      unit=\unexpanded\expandafter{\thisunit}]{\thisref}{\thisname}%%  
    }%
}
\makeatother
```

With both examples it is recommendable to have default-definitions for the macros `\thisunit`, `\thisref`, `\thisdescription` and `\thisname`.